# How do I view hidden type variables in Isabelle proof goals?

Tags: isabelle

In Isabelle, one can often hit proof goals where the intermediate type of terms is critical to a proof's correctness. For instance, consider the following lemma converting the `nat` 42 into an `'a word` then back again:

```
theory Test
imports "~~/src/HOL/Word/Word"
begin

lemma "unat (of_nat 42) = 42"
  ...
```

Now the truth of this statement depends on the type of `of_nat 42`: if it is `32 word`, then the statement is true, if it is a `2 word`, however, the statement is false.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get Isabelle to display this intermediate type to me.

I have tried the following:

- `declare [[show_types]]`
- `declare [[show_sorts]]`
- `local_setup {* Config.put show_all_types true *}`

all of which just display:

```
unat (of_nat (42::nat)) = (42::nat)
```

In a pinch, one can do:

```
apply (tactic {* (fn t => (tracing (PolyML.makestring (prems_of t)); all_tac t))  *})
```

do get a raw dump of the `term`, but I was hoping there was a better way.

**Is there a good way of displaying intermediate term types in a proof goal?**

Comment: Just for clarification: you are referring to `unat` from `~/src/HOL/Word/Word`, right? (Not that this is relevant for an answer, but it might help later visitors to reproduce your problem.)

Comment: Btw: In the line below "all of which just display" I guess you meant `42` instead of `3`?

Comment: @chris: Thanks. I have updated both.

Answer (score 4):

In Isabelle/jEdit you can always "control-hover" (i.e., keep the control-button pressed and hover the mouse) over a constant in order to get additional information. For `of_nat` in

```
lemma "unat (of_nat 42) = 42"
```

This results in

```
constant "Nat.semiring_1_class.of_nat"
:: nat => 'a word
```

Now you can recursively do the same on `'a` of `'a word` and will get

```
:: len
free type variable
```

which tells you that `'a` is of sort `len` (by control-clicking `len`, you could directly jump to the definition of this type class, which is also quite handy).

So the answer to your question is: yes, control-hover in Isabelle/jEdit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was aware of that jEdit feature, but didn't think to use it in this context. I would really like to be able to have the types displayed in the output though, so I can copy/paste the result, diff against another term, etc.

Answer (score 4):

To make Isabelle show you the type of unat in this example, you want to declare the following:

```
  declare [[show_types]]
  declare [[show_sorts]]
  declare [[show_consts]]
```

The last line prints the type of each constant used in the goal in the output window. This works both in jEdit and ProofGeneral.

There is a problem with this solution: if unat occurs multiple times with different types, it will print all these instances, but it will not tell you which type instance is which occurrence. Apart from the jEdit hover, I don't know of any solution for that, though.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about `show_consts`. Looks useful for when the `show_all_types` feature is too hideous to contemplate, though still means you can't just copy/paste the result into a new theorem.

Comment: Yes, copy/paste into new theorems remains a problem. I don't have a good solution for that.

Answer (score 2):

Running the command:

```
setup {* Config.put_global show_all_types true *}
```

seems to do the trick.

The goal `unat (of_nat 3) = 3` becomes the hideous (but complete):

```
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. (Trueprop::bool => prop)
     ((op =::nat => nat => bool)
       ((unat::'a word => nat)
         ((of_nat::nat => 'a word)
           ((numeral::num => nat)
             ((num.Bit1::num => num) (num.One::num)))))
       ((numeral::num => nat)
         ((num.Bit1::num => num) (num.One::num))))
```

as desired.

It is interesting that a `declare [[show_all_types]]` does not work; the source looks like it should. Perhaps it is a bug in Isabelle2013?

Comment: The tracker for bug requests and feature reports is the `isabelle-users` mailing list.  All these `show_` options are a bit hard to track.  Note that `show_markup` modifies the way how things work in Isabelle/jEdit more fundamentally -- it is also explained in NEWS and isar-ref manual.